# Any freely available large stellar spectra catalog?

Tags: data-analysis

For a non-astronomy personal project I would like to have a large set of optical stellar spectra combined with absolute magnitude when available. I search for a dataset that contains 10k - 10M objects, with total compressed size below 100Gb (ideally below 10Gb), is freely available via ftp/http/rsync and machine-readable. Presence of most 'naked eye visible' stars and their individual names in the set is desired, but not required.

I know that some digital survey data are freely available via FTP, so maybe some reasonable spectral data catalog exists as well?

Note, I'm planning to download the data for local processing, so retrieving them through on-line forms (or even automated http interfaces) is undesirable.

The best I was able to find is this [catalog](http://www.as.utexas.edu/~hebe/s4n/data.html)  . Dropping aside that FITS is not something I'm used to (this apparentrly can be rectified) it is too small. I'd like at least 1k stars, 10k preferable. There is apparently a lot of surveys in 0.1-10k objects range that are focused on specific type of stars (say, nearby M-class dwarfs) and stellar libraries containing spectral data on representative objects from various classes. However I'd like a 'representative set' here, which contains stars of various nature in proportion similar to their 'natural abundance' in some region. An example would be the set of stars of solar neighborhood above, but again it's too small.

Comment: NOMAD http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/nomad perhaps? You can download the entire catalog (I've done so), so it's not just form access.

Comment: @barrycarter see update

Comment: Have you not come across the [Sloan Digital Sky Survey](http://www.sdss.org/)? From the information on the latest data release ([DR12](http://www.sdss.org/dr12/scope/)), it looks to me like there are as many as a million stellar spectra in there.

Comment: Agreed. SDSS is the thing to look at. I believe they have made the spectr available. Get used to FITS. I don;t think RAVE have released the spectra?

Comment: @RobJeffries afaik RAVE used quite narrow range of wavelength. It could be useful, but it isn't ideal

Comment: @Warrick SDSS is my last resort choice. I would have to either live without absolute magnitudes or to identify objects of interest in some other catalogue.

Comment: You will have to wait a few years for the full Gaia data release, which will contain spectra of all stars down to about 15th magnitude, with parallaxes. What you want does not exist now. Even at 15th mag, this will be incomplete for the lowest mass stars, even within the 1000 closest stars. (And the Gaia spectra will be a limited wavelength range).